# DIY not on the Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

I've just noticed that we're not on the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) despite being graduated for nearly a year.

Is this deliberate or just an oversight?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a simple oversight, will sort it out next time I update data explorer.